# Fontawesome5 SVG with JS in css?

Tags: svg, font-awesome

I am trying to use FA5 SVG with JS in css block, but I don't seem to get it working. I search Stack overflow but I found results for CSS version but not SVG version.
I added the following javascript in my head code

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
```

And I used below code in my css

```
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
font-weight: 400;
margin-right: 5px;
font-size: 13px;
content: "\f1f8";
```

I am trying to add below icon https://fontawesome.com/icons/trash?style=solid

Answer (score 2):

You can actually enable that in JS+SVG mode, too.

However, be warned, [it will make replacement **really** slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50976897/3423324).

In the recent [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements#gotta-enable-this-with-svg) they added a hint:

> #### Gotta enable this with SVG
>
> If you are using SVG with JavaScript you need to enable this because it's disabled by default. Use `<script data-search-pseudo-elements ... >` inside your script tag.

This is described in more detail  [in the configuration documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/configuration#searchpseudoelements):

```
<head>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/js/all.js" data-search-pseudo-elements></script>
  <style>
  .glasses::before {
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Solid';
    content: "\f530";
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <span class="glasses"></span>
</body>
```

> Valid `font-family` values are: `"Font Awesome 5 Solid"`, `"Font Awesome 5 Regular"`, `"Font Awesome 5 Light"`, and `"Font Awesome 5 Brands"`.

---

### Concrete example

In my case I had a table and want those arrows to indicate sorting:

```css
th.sort-down::after {display: none; font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Solid'; content: "\f0dd"; /* fas fa-sort-up   */}
th.sort-up::after   {display: none; font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Solid'; content: "\f0de"; /* fas fa-sort-down */}
th::after           {display: none; font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Solid'; content: "\f0dc"; /* fas fa-sort */}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/js/all.js" data-search-pseudo-elements></script>

<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>no sort</th>
    <th class="sort-down">sorted down</th>
    <th class="sort-up">sorted up</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

That said, you might be better of (performance wise) by putting the icons into html, and use the css to display or hide it can work, too:

```css
th.sort-up   .fa-sort      {display: none;}
th.sort-up   .fa-sort-up   {display: inline;}
th.sort-down .fa-sort      {display: none;}
th.sort-down .fa-sort-down {display: inline;}
th .fa-sort-up, th .fa-sort-down {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/js/all.js" data-search-pseudo-elements></script>
    
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>
      no sort
      <i class="fas fa-sort"></i><i class="fas fa-sort-up"></i><i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
    </th>
    <th class="sort-down">
      sorted down
      <i class="fas fa-sort"></i><i class="fas fa-sort-up"></i><i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
    </th>
    <th class="sort-up">
      sorted up
      <i class="fas fa-sort"></i><i class="fas fa-sort-up"></i><i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also a viable option is to just using the "old" CSS+Fonts way instead of the javascript+SVG version.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use just refer to the FA-Icons in your CSS when you want to use the SVG-Icons, that will only work when using CSS. To use SVG, you have to have references to "`fas fa-trash`" in our code (which the JS will then replace with the appropriate SVG)

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
```

Comment: Is there no way I can use icon in css if I am using SVG ? Can't I use any SVG icon image to make it work ?

Comment: The CSS relies on a webfont, SVG is a completely different game w/o the webfont. I guess you could make it work by loading the font independently, but it might be a painful excercise. But before looking into that, can you explain the *real* problem which led to this idea - perhaps there is a better plan of attack...

Comment: Sorry for late reply, the reason why I want to use SVG version is I wrote a css file based on FA4 which has all icons in the css. But now I have FA5 with SVG and I wanted to modify my old css files with the new FA codes.

Comment: Anyways, I read documentation of FA and it is not recommended to use this method. Anyone interested to try this, can refer this here
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#additional-styling